# How to: Sort user by values and theier new position in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying sort all the users in the database by a value and give them a new ID, that will act as their position.

[image]

I've tried to order them descending by `money`, that's the value I'm looking for to order by, but I wasn't able to properly update each user's ID in order.

Please note, the database has over 5000 entries, so I need a way that won't lag out the database.

Comment: Does everyone have a different value of money? If not, how do you want to sort X people who all have the same amount of money?

Comment: You want to basically replace the id column with a row number?  This doesn't sound like a very good idea...

Comment: The money value varies, there can be people that will have the same ammount of money at a time.

The goal is to get the ID or another Column to have the row's number after the sorting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rank function in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/rank-function-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't have a nice easy `RANK()` function. You can use a workaround like what is described here though: [Rank function in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/rank-function-in-mysql)

```
SELECT t1.*, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM table_name t1, (
SELECT @curRank := 0
) t2
ORDER BY money
```

Comment: technically that's a corollary of other databases' row_number() rather than rank()..